# Extracting strings from text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a file `compile2.txt` with the following data in it:

---

```
Compile log of application: Information
Version: 1.0    Revision: 940
Compile date/time: 04/02/2013 05:03:16 
Elapsed time: 5.53 seconds
Summary: Total of 917 steps and 127 objects compiled.
         Total errors(0) and warnings(0).

--- End of compile report ---
```

---

I need to extract the application, revision and date/time information using a batch file. How can I achieve this? The expected output should be as follows:

```
Information 940 04/02/2013 05:03:16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (compile2.txt) do (
    set linec=%%a
    set linetest=!linec:Compile log of application=!
    IF NOT [!linec!]==[!linetest!] set app=!linec:Compile log of application: =!
    set linetest=!linec: Revision=!
    IF NOT [!linec!]==[!linetest!] set rev=!linec:Version: 1.0    Revision: =!
    set linetest=!linec:Compile date/time: =!
    IF NOT [!linec!]==[!linetest!] set when=!linec:Compile date/time: =!
)
echo !app! - !rev! @ !when!
ENDLOCAL
pause
```

Run that and see if that gives you what you want