# Extract Strings from a text file into another text file? In .bat

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file, text-files

I have a text file that contains names of all the files in my directory followed by its date.

Is it possible in batch/bash to extract those files names from the text file and its date based on a value on the string.

I have already checked [Extracting strings from text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971803/extracting-strings-from-text-file)
but this does not answer my query. I have also checked numerous others including [Get specific string from a text file using batch command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243585/get-specific-string-from-a-text-file-using-batch-command) and seems to hit a dead end as it doesn't get all the lines from the whole text file.

a typical string/file name looks like this

> 5f367f72-9e2f-4f89-b3d6-2cdafed17d94_IRO_RMUSI_SONG_TimayaKingPerryy_KomKom.mxf_A1.MXF,25/07/2019 05:47:24

The identifier is IRO. i have more files in the text file as well but I want it to be able to look at the text file, find everything that has the identifier and make a new text file with the IRO file and date populated.

There are about 150,000 +/- line of string so manually doing this wont be easy.

If its possible to be done in a batch-file i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite easy if you think about it. Filter your file with `findstr "_IRO_"`), then split the filename from the date  with a `for /f` loop (according to your example, they are delimited with a comma):

```
(for /f "delims=," %%a in ('type "names.txt" ^|findstr "_IRO_"') do @echo %%a) > "newnames.txt"
```

Note: to execute it directly from a command line instead of in a batch file, replace every `%%a` with `%a`.

Comment: Hi, the output this generates is empty.
It returns a new file but comes up blank. i passed the file path to the and replaced it with the names.txt

Comment: it can't be empty if the names file exists, is in the same folder as the batch file and contains at least one line containing `_IRO_`.

Comment: If the file path and/or the file's name contains spaces, quote it like `... in ('<"c:\path to  file\names.txt" findstr ...`

Comment: Yep, it is. the names.txt in my case has 25 files names as shown above with the IRO  ID

Comment: even with the quotes marks added. the output file is empty

Comment: is there a way for me to upload the sample text file? so i can show you how it looks

Comment: On the command line, do a simple `<names.txt findstr "_IRO_"` and report what it says.

Comment: Why using input redirection (`<`) with `findstr`? Let me recommend to use `findstr /L "_IRO_" "names.txt"` since `findstr` might hang in case `names.txt` is not terminated with a final line-break...

Comment: @aschipfl redirection is faster, but you have a point with the possible missing line-break at the end. (I'm not sure, whether `findstr "string" "file"` has the same problem, so I changed to `type "file" | findstr "string"`, as `type` adds the line-break if not present). (On the other hand - we could simply use `find` instead of `findstr`...)

Comment: Redirection is faster? really?? I'm surprised! I'd expect the opposite. Anyway, piping does not have a problem with missing final line-break. But both redirection and piping limit the lime length to 8191 characters (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8844868))...

Comment: @aschipfl: maybe I remember incorrectly or confuse it with something else.

Comment: @APerson I rechecked. It works at my end. Do you get any messages on the screen?

Comment: Just tested with a 0.5 GiB file (64 Ki lines with 8190 bytes each, excl. the line-breaks): `findstr "^" "huge.txt" > nul` lasts 1.6 s on my system, `findstr "^" < "huge.txt" > nul` lasts 2.0 s; piping is hard to measure since there's another command `type` involved...

Comment: @Stephan, I tried it now and it work perfectly thanks